# TypeScript error with multiple return types

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript to declare the type of some data which is returned from an API call.

If the API call succeeds the data structure looks different than if the API fails.

I declare my types as follows:

```
interface SubmissionDetails {
  clientAddress1: string
  clientAddress2: string
  clientCity: string
  clientContactEmail: string
  clientContactFullName: string
  clientName: string
  clientState: string
  clientZip: string
  namedInsured: string
  underwriterDisplayName: string
}

  getSubmission: (
    appTypeId: string,
    submissionId: string
  ) => Promise<SubmissionDetails | { message: string }>
```

So if the API succeeds we get the `SubmissionDetails` type and if it fails we simply get a `message`.

I want to set a constant equal to the `message` value if the API fails.

```
const errorMessage = submissionDetails.message
```

However this gives me an error stating:

```
Property 'message' does not exist on type 'SubmissionDetails | { message: string; }'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'SubmissionDetails'.
```

I understand that this is telling me `message` doesn't exist on `SubmissionDetails`.

Is there a simple way to fix this error so that I can set `errorMessage` equal to the `message` when it exists and `null` or `void` if it doesn't exist?

Comment: It seems like that should be a _rejection_, not resolving with an error state. But there are various options for narrowing at compile _and_ runtime: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: You can use `Partial<SubmissionDetails & {message: string}>`. This means that you will create an interface that will consist of both `SubmissionDetails` and `{message: string}` and `Partial` to set all of the fields to not required. Then just do: `if(submissionDetails.message)` then there is an error

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the awaited value returned by `getSubmission()` has a `message` property. This [*narrows*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the `submissionDetails` and you can access the error message with `submissionDetails.message`.

```
interface SubmissionDetails {
  clientAddress1: string;
  clientAddress2: string;
  clientCity: string;
  clientContactEmail: string;
  clientContactFullName: string;
  clientName: string;
  clientState: string;
  clientZip: string;
  namedInsured: string;
  underwriterDisplayName: string;
}

declare function getSubmission(
  appTypeId: string,
  submissionId: string,
): Promise<SubmissionDetails | { message: string }>;

(async () => {
  const submissionDetails = await getSubmission("someId", "someId");
  let errorMessage: string;

  if ("message" in submissionDetails) {
    errorMessage = submissionDetails.message;
  }
})();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGBbYBnPYAexABEIw5gAbPZAbwChlkFrgJwBBAEx6ggEAjAC5keMFFABzANzNW7TmF79BeAExiJUkHIVsO4AMLAwAT22SZ8loeXGSlBGACi2KtSu79dpSadEMAAxdGpqADk4bAhvGwN-MCiYuL1bRSMwVEpIVN8M5QAtYAAHPPSQaIgeAEkQPHQBHnKFdBAeaAB3KUgoUnwS6jhzZNjxazTGAF9GRg62OAFkGDaXYhBkaQoMHHxCEgAKBTgSkoAVcxKIGubxnwAaBQbdgnWbvMeASjEABSgiXB4CAAHh2gP2ZAonjoAB8GMgYgQ4Fs8sgpgA%20eSMA5wPDmEAIZAHT7IAC86IYBhIEnEWHB63IlBodFJyDgnSoYE22zpe3WBwARHgAdceAL7sghSKbgLPulqBRkNB-lAALLqZFjHTxBTAGBEgWIvCagXIUC0l4QxnQklMFgsZVENUarZki30kjW5kAOiNmvSMymn2J8iAA)